# Get HTTP headers on WebKit.NET

Tags: c#, .net, http, webkit, webkit.net

I've been trying to figure out how to handle 401 responses on `WebKit.NET` and show an authentication box so that user can enter his credentials and then send them back to the server.

[This guy](https://github.com/therealmitchconnors/webkitdotnet/commit/e4fba420ff9146a951eab90f9647711a727b6574) figured a way to add the proper headers to a new request and send them to the server, but seems like the code is sending them to every page that the browser navigates to which is not what I want. I dug a bit into the code and there is this interface called `IWebResourceLoadDelegate` which among other contains two event handlers called `didReceiveResponse` and `didReceiveContentLength` that will be called for every response, but can't figure out how in the world to read the headers from the parameters being passed. I think the header is just not being passed at all.

Also, seems like the guys at [web kit sharp](http://code.google.com/p/open-webkit-sharp/) haven't solve this issue either, but somehow Chrome does handles it properly. I'm not sure which build of WebKit Chrome uses. I just hope is not a custom build such that I won't have a choice other than spending the rest of my life trying to build WebKit (and the other rest trying to add the missing functionality).

Any one has any idea how could I begin to figure out how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked on this project in some time, but it looks to me like you should be able to get the request headers from the [WebURLResponse](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebKit/win/WebURLResponse.cpp) object, perhaps from the allHeaderFields or statusCode methods...

It would be really great if you could finish my work to get full HTTP Auth support in WebKit.NET.  I just haven't had the time... Chrome and Safari have their own proprietary implementations that do the trick.

Comment: This is strange. The `IWebURLResponse` interface (which is the only interface the `WebURLResponse` class in the WebKit used by WebKit.NET implements) doesn't have methods to read the header, but the [WebURLResponse](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebKit/win/WebURLResponse.h) in the trunk also implements `IWebHTTPURLResponse`, which does have methods to read  the header. Could they be using an older version of WebKit? Or is this an Apple - Windows issue.

Comment: The code I linked to was a webkit for windows file, and those methods have existed as long as the file has been in source control (3yrs).  I know WebKit.NET gets behind on WebKit Source, but I don't think it's that far behind...